# iPhone - Can we parse .plist(xml) file using NSXMLParser?

Tags: iphone, xml, plist, nsxmlparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing XML in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa)

iPhone - Can we parse .plist(xml) file using NSXMLParser?

Comment: this should do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely use the NSXMLParser to parse an xml plist file. However, it is much, `much`, **much**, easier to simply use the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class to do that.

Answer (score 4):

There are simpler ways of reading a plist file. You can use the following method for `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```