# IOS XML Parsing without attribute dict object for key?

Tags: ios, xml

I have an XML file which looks like this

```
<data>

<value>33</value>

</data>
```

Im trying to parse it but Im not sure how because every single tutorial on the web I have seen so far tells you how to do it with an XML element which looks like this:

```
<value id="somestupididhere"></value>
```

I want to do it without the "id=" bit. How do I allocate the value of a tag without having to add an id to it?

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: Dave Delong's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa/1090170#1090170).

Comment: Ahh so I dont need to do anything when it comes to Attributedict ObjextForKey then. Thanks! Il give it a try